# Windows 10 File Explorer slow update

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, file-management

I have a problem with Win 10 File Explorer. Every time an update occurs on a folder, File Explore take long time to update and often needs a manual update.

For example: if I create a new folder on the desktop, that needs 20-30 seconds before showing in File Explorer and even more to show on the desktop. The same happens if I delete or copy a file or a folder, forcing me the most of the times using F5 nearly every time I use FE.

Does anyone have the same problem? Does anyone know how to get rid of this?

Comment: This typically happens if there is a context error..  You can try looking for these with Nirsoft Shell View to see if you can find it.

Comment: @John can you explaine better, please? Are context errors related to environment variables?

Comment: Context errors can occur in File Explorer when you right click on something. That causes the slowness if there is a context error.

Comment: My context menu seems to work well. The issue I described appears only with basic operations on files, like copy, paste, create new and delete.

Comment: I understand but if there are context errors, copy and paste go bad as well. I am merely offering what I have seen happen. It could be something else of course, but I have just offered the most common.

Comment: Sure, I wasn't saying the one you report is not an option. I was only try to understand better and ensuring I explained the problem in details. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Does this behavior happen in Safe Mode.  Instead of replying with a comment you should [edit] your question instead.

Comment: This is probably related to a misbehaving shell extension.  I don't understand the term "context error" and have written countless shell extensions (probably my ignorance).  The context menu is just another interface.  Every time you click or do something in the file explorer, several COM objects are queried.  Many/most of these don't belong to Microsoft (like say adobe reader or dropbox).  Any one of these can hold up the process and prevent expected behavior. Microsoft is not without error but your problem is probably related to something you installed that added an extension.